# Trouble with the base representation theorem

Tags: elementary-number-theory

I'm reading an elementary introduction to number theory and I've hit a bit
of a stumbling block with their proof for the base representation theorem.

I've included a link to the book's statement of the theorem and the first part of the proof:

[image]

Here's my problem: if all the $a_j$'s with $j <k$ are 0, wouldn't $n+t =  a_kb^k$, instead of $a_k$?

Can someone explain what's going on here?

Comment: It's a typo. Your proposed fix is correct. Your book appears to adopt the convention that $0$ is not a member of $\Bbb{N}$ (otherwise the theorem and the claim are not true as stated). I had hoped this convention was dying out, but it seems not to be.

Comment: So say we fix the typo by replacing $b^n=n+t=a_k$ with $b^n=n+t=a_k b^k$. Now where is the contradiction?

Comment: Your proposed fix does indeed fix that small step, but you are quite right that the other parts of the argument are flawed. $b^n$ has exactly one base $b$ representation and that has $a_n = 1$ and $a_j = 0$ for $j \neq n$. So we have $k = n$ and $a_j = 0$ for $j < k$ contrary to what the book claims. What is this book? I would advise you to find a better one, if you can!